# Como obtener primer nth-child o first-child con span usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quería tener el primer nth-child, que se rellenan dinámicamente mediante agregación y no sé cómo conseguirlo.

```js
$("ul > li > a > span.menu-item-text:nth-child(1)").text("Primer Inicio");
```

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="test static">
      <li class="static">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-item-text">Frist (solo quiere cambiar "Primer Inicio")</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-item-text">Two</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-item-text">Tree</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Mejor agregale una clase que la diferencie de las demás.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para completar a las otras respuestas y viendo tu código, te dejo algunos ejemplos de referencia con diferentes posibilidades:

- [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) - `$('.menu-item-text:first').text("Primer Inicio");`
- [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) - `$('.menu-item-text:eq(0)').text("Primer Inicio");`
- [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) - `$('.menu-item-text:lt(1)').text("Primer Inicio");`
- [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) - `$('.menu-item-text').filter(':first').text("Primer Inicio");`
- [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) - `$('ul a').children(':first').text("Primer Inicio");`
- [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) - `$('ul a span').first().text("Primer Inicio");`

Answer (score 6):

Tu ejemplo no funciona porque todos los `span.menu-item-text` son `:nth-child(1)` dentro de cada `<a />` una opción es que utilices el selector `:eq()`:

```
$("ul > li > a > span.menu-item-text:eq(0)").text("Primer Inicio");
```

o bien aplicar `:nth-child(1)` a la lista de `<li/>`:

```
$("ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > span.menu-item-text").text("Primer Inicio");
```

Comment: Gracias por explicame

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema es que estás obteniendo todo *span* que sea **primer hijo** y todos los *span* son primeros hijos (de *a*). En su lugar debes obtener el primer *li* y referenciar al *span*.

> Cuando quieres obtener el primer hijo, basta con usar el pseudo selector `first-child`

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li:first-child a span').text('Primer inicio');
```

**JavaScript (puro)**

```
document.querySelector('ul li:first-child a span').textContent = 'Primer inicio';
```

```js
$('ul li:first-child a span').text("Primer Inicio");
```

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="test static">
      <li class="static">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-item-text">Frist (solo quiere cambiar "Primer Inicio")</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-item-text">Two</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-item-text">Tree</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: pero puede agregar asi es o no?
  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.querySelector('ul li:first-child a span.menu-item-text').textContent = 'Inicio';
   });

Comment: Es correcto. Básicamente estás diciendo: seleccióname *del primer li, el span con clase "menu-item-text" dentro de a*.